# ArcGIS Survey Analyst extension not working on Windows 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-9.3, windows-10, survey-analyst

I am using ArcMap 9.3 for some digitization work. I have survey data from total station, data are comma seprated has pointid, northing, esting, height and comments as below

```
6001,3052500.000,532500.000,1000.000,
6005,3052500.000,532568.219,1000.000,
1,3052495.945,532477.080,1000.063,HC
2,3052494.001,532493.357,1000.055,HC
```

I am using Survey Analyst Extension to import point data. It works well in windows7 but not working on win8 and 10.

[image: Import data]

Every steps of the Import Survey Data Wizard works well but it does not respond on click of finish button.

What might be possible solution to make this work on windows 10?

Comment: ArcMap 9.3 is so old that it is no longer supported by Esri and it may not work on Windows 10, though it is just as likely to be a 32/64 bit issue. Consider upgrading to at least 10.2 or 10.3 for compatibility with more recent versions of Windows where you can at least get some Esri support.

Comment: 10.3.1 was the first release of ArcGIS certified on Windows 10, so 10.2 and 10.3 are too old as well.

Answer (score 4):

ArcGIS Survey Analyst was an extension product for ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1, and earlier, that was [deprecated at ArcGIS 9.3.1](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51222) and did not ship with ArcGIS 10.

The [ArcGIS 9.3.1 System Requirements included Windows 7](http://downloads.esri.com/support/systemrequirements/ArcGIS_Desktop_93_SystemRequirements.pdf) (with some limitations) but no later OS versions.

ArcGIS 9.3.1 was [retired for support on 31 Dec 2013](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/12/20/retirement-of-arcgis-9-3-arcgis-9-3-1/).

With such a new operating system (Windows 10) and such old GIS software (ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 and Survey Analyst), I would not expect your configuration to work, and I would not think help to get an unsupported OS version working with a retired GIS software version is likely to be forthcoming from anywhere.